# IDistributedCache: Does Refresh/RefreshAsync actually refresh Cache values or just Expiry Time

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core

I am trying to decipher whether [Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.distributed.idistributedcache.refresh?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) in IDistributedCache for Sql Server actually updates the Value of the cache.

Comment: No, if it has [sliding expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.slidingexpiration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) then this call resets it.

Comment: @GuruStron so there's no way of updating cache unless I allow it to expire

Comment: You just set a new value with `IDistributedCache.Set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if cache item has [sliding expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.slidingexpiration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) then this call resets it. To update value you can just set a new value with `IDistributedCache.Set`.